# Books like Concrete Mathematics for Mathematicians

Tags: combinatorics

I find Concrete Mathematics http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/gkp.html really useful for the asymptotic analysis of complicated combinatial sums. Are there any similar books (for the advanced maths student), maybe containing better proofs of the results and and cover integrals (always as part as a complicated sum)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might like Analytic Combinatorics by Flajolet and Sedgewick.

Comment: And the book is here... http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf